# Cursor vs standard SQL

Tags: sql

I have seen the following question approached to be solved as a cursor although I seen efficiency doing it as a multiple join. How can I solve this via a cursor and should i bother doing so as im extracting it via excel?

```
RecordID EmpID  FirstName   LastName    HiredDate   FiredDate
1111     1      John        Flanagan    1/02/2013   1/02/2014
2222     1      Michael     Richards    1/01/2014   1/02/2015
3333     3      Peter       Johnson     1/08/2014   1/07/2016
4444     3      Jim         Crow        1/09/2014   1/02/2017
5555     3      Own         Wilson      1/010/2014  1/03/2015
```

Here's my attempt with SQL initially.

```
select EmpID, count(RecordID), HiredDate 
from Employer 
group by EmpID 
order by DESC.
```

Need to write a query that returns each individual employer and for each row include the max employees that were hired by the company and the date of the last hire.

I was asked to write it as a cursor as they wanted to extract the above data line by line from excel.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Comment: The `group by` usage is invalid SQL. Also: please [edit] your question and add the expected output based on your sample data.

Comment: Why do different persons share the same EmpID?

Comment: EmpID is that they worked for the same company.

Comment: I was asked to write it as a cursor as they wanted to extract the above data line by line from excel.

Answer (score 0):

If EmpId is employer id you are almost there:

```
SELECT EmpID, COUNT(RecordID), MAX(HiredDate)
FROM Employer 
GROUP BY EmpID 
ORDER BY EmpID ASC
```

This will get you the output you require, but I'm not sure what you wanted to order by...I've assumed EmpId.

I've also assumed SQL Server.

Comment: `ASC` is default and thus no need of specifying

Comment: Hi @Rahul, I was highlighting the difference to the code in OP's original question. But otherwise I agree completely.

Comment: see above comments about cursor but thanks for the assistance in putting together the alternative SQL version.